# Invoke Windows password dialog when using NET USE

Tags: windows-authentication, vbscript, command-line-interface

I'll try to get to the point.

Using Run from the start menu to an un-authenticated machine: `\\hostname\share` gives me the Windows prompt for password, good.

Running `%systemroot%\explorer.exe "\\hostname\share"` against the same un-authenticated machines hangs for a moment, then opens up my local My Documents, no prompts for password, bad.

Running `%systemroot%\explorer.exe "\\server\share"` against a domain server, opens an explorer window to the share, good.

How can I get the Windows password dialog to present itself when attempting to connect to an un-authenticated machine? Im aware of running `net use \\server\share` and inputting the username and password when prompted inside the command window, but that's not what I want. We are open to basic commands or a vbs script.

The reason for this is that a lot of our clients run in peer to peer networks, and their laptops that run our software are not able to authenticate with a server until they provide a username and  password, we are trying to avoid the command window, and provide a familiar Windows password dialog. We use SQL merge replication, and aside from sync, which uses SQL auth, they need to be able to access a share which contains the initial snapshot at installation time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start` seems to show the password prompt

```
start \\server\share
```

Comment: I think you are on to something, let me do a little testing here.

Comment: We ended up writing a custom window, but this is still useful information, so I'm marking it as the answer.